# Display settings in 2 monitors in Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I am using Kubuntu now, but I'm having a problem with the display settings. It only has global display settings, but I want to adjust the scale on the two monitors differently. How do I do that?

I've searched in videos and forums for the solution, and I expected it to be pretty easy.